# No of times text is appearing in a sentence

Tags: r

There is a dataframe that contains words in a sentence like below. I need a output that shows no of times each word is appearing.

`Column 1
Electronic, socket, clamp, cooler
Actuator, cylinder, valve
Hydraulic, electronic, cooler
Actuator, Pnematic, cylinder, valve`

I need the below output

`Column 2    Column 3
Eletronic   2
Socket      1
clamp       1
cooler      2
actuator    2
cylinder    2
valve       2
Hydraulic   1
Electronic  1
Pneumatic   1`

Comment: It highly depends on how you are reading in the data. Is that a CSV file with just 1 column where each set of values is enclosed by quotes?

Comment: Yes your correct. It is only 1 column in a data sets

Comment: Why do you have two electronics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a base R option.  We can try using `sapply` with `strsplit` to generate a list of character vectors, deriving from the original CSV content.  Then, we can `unlist` that list to generate a single vector of terms, and then aggregate by term to generate the counts.

```
df <- data.frame(v1=c("Electronic, socket, clamp, cooler",
                      "Actuator, cylinder, valve", "Hydraulic, electronic, cooler",
                      "Actuator, Pnematic, cylinder, valve"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
out <- unlist(sapply(df$v1, function(x) { strsplit(x, ",\\s*") }))
aggregate(out, by=list(col2=out), FUN=length)

         col2 x
1    Actuator 2
2  Electronic 1
3   Hydraulic 1
4    Pnematic 1
5       clamp 1
6      cooler 2
7    cylinder 2
8  electronic 1
9      socket 1
10      valve 2
```

Note that storing unnormalized CSV data in R (or really any data tool) is not optimal, and will make working with that data difficult.

**Edit:**

The above code assumes that the `v1` column is *character*, and not factor.  The code won't work on factor data, and would generate the "non-character argument" error.

Comment: Thanks Tim. May i know what is this code means ' strsplit(x, ",\\s*" ' ???  I mean what it does

Comment: This says to take a CSV value like `"a, b, c"`, and then split it into separate terms, using comma followed by any amount of whitespace (read: spaces) as the separator.  So, conceptually this generates `[a, b, c]`.

Comment: Hi Tim, When I apply to the large data set, I am getting error like  "Error in strsplit(x1, ",\\s*") : non-character argument"

Comment: @Rlearn You probably are trying to do this on a factor column.  `strsplit` will only work on a character column.  I will edit my answer.

Comment: Hi Tim, I clicked on the top arrow. Thats it right? Is it how I mark?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's read in like this and formatted this way:

```
x <- read.table(text="'Column 1'
'Electronic, socket, clamp, cooler'
'Actuator, cylinder, valve'
'Hydraulic, electronic, cooler'
'Actuator, Pnematic, cylinder, valve'", header = TRUE)

data.frame(table(unlist(strsplit(x[,1], ","))))
```

Comment: You're missing an aggregation step.

Comment: Hi tcash. I am getting an error after executing last step                                                     
                                                                                                            
> data.frame(table(unlist(strsplit(x[,1], ","))))                                                     Error in strsplit(x[, 1], ",") : non-character argument